# How to add more indentation for section in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I would like to move sections in my TOC more to the right =) The picture will explain all:

[image]

Here is my code so far (This code will give me the upper part in the picture):

```
\newgeometry{hmargin={3cm,3cm},vmargin={3cm,4cm}}
% SISÄLLYSLUETTELO

\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2cm}
\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.3em}{.6em}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sisällysluettelo}

\doublespacing
\large \tableofcontents
\singlespacing

\restoregeometry
```

Now even if I try to modify the length in `\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2cm}` the section stays where it is...any ideas why? What am I doing wrong x) Thank you for your help! =)

UPDATE =) If I remove the `\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.3em}{.6em}` from the code above, I get this:

[image]

Now the subsections stay where they are and section goes to bold :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2cm}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{4cm}
\dottedcontents{section}[1.5em]{}{1.3em}{.6em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo}
\subsection{bar}
\subsubsection{baz}
foobar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer =) Unfortunately it doesn't help me...the section stays where it is...I noticed that If I remove the `\dottedcontents` I can change the indentations, but then the section goes to bold and looses the dots... :S I think your code moves subsection and subsubsection? =) Or should I replace sections in my code with subsections? =) My document structure at the moment is : PART --> SECTION --> SUBSECTION. Should it be: SECTION --> SUBSECTION --> SUBSUBSECTION? =)

Comment: as long as you do not provide a _complete_ example I do not know what you really mean.

Comment: +1 Don't worry about it =) I got it already using your answer =) I just changed all `\part`s to `\section`s etc. and your code started to work =) Thank you for your help! =)

Answer (score 13):

In order to modify indentation in the table of contents, you can modify the definition of `\l@chapter`, `l@section` or `l@subsection` (as you wish).
The first value (`1.5em` in the example below) affects the global indent and the second (`3.0em`) increase the indentation between number and section name.
Add these three lines in the main source file to add an extra indent between the number and the text of all sections (with respect to the official `book.cls`)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.0em}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 for not requirering additional packages.

Comment: +1 for not requirering additional packages.